# How to count distinct column values in Google Sheets?

Tags: count, google-sheets, distinct

I have a Google spreadsheet with a column that looks like this:

```
City
----
London
Paris
London
Berlin
Rome
Paris
```

I want to count the appearances of each distinct city (so I need the city name and the number of appearances).

```
City   | Count
-------+------
London |  2
Paris  |  2
Berlin |  1
Rome   |  1
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Deleted my answer due to I wasn't able to create a working example. I recommend having a look at a combination with `IF()` and `COUNTIF()`

Answer (score 118, accepted):

[**Link to Working Examples**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17IbCf_TYVHRxd-JwOgjx2cxX06hu8OwlI2Ua1pa9Os8)

**Solution 0**

This can be accompished using pivot tables.

[image: Pivot table Example - Count rows by value]

**Solution 1**

Use the `unique` formula to get all the distinct values. Then use `countif` to get the count of each value. See the working example link at the top to see exactly how this is implemented.

```
Unique Values        Count
=UNIQUE(A3:A8)       =COUNTIF(A3:A8;B3)
                     =COUNTIF(A3:A8;B4)
                     ...
```

**Solution 2**

If you setup your data as such:

```
City    
----    
London   1
Paris    1
London   1
Berlin   1
Rome     1
Paris    1
```

Then the following will produce the desired result.

```
=sort(transpose(query(A3:B8,"Select sum(B) pivot (A)")),2,FALSE)
```

I'm sure there is a way to get rid of the second column since all values will be 1. Not an ideal solution in my opinion.

via http://googledocsforlife.blogspot.com/2011/12/counting-unique-values-of-data-set.html

**Other Possibly Helpful Links**

- http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/a5qFC4pFZJ8

Comment: for solution 2: you could leave column B empty and then use "count" instead of "sum": =sort(transpose(query(A3:B8,"Select count(B) pivot (A)")),2,FALSE)

Comment: ...but how do I create a pivot table ?
while this answer looks great and detailed, dnlbrky's more straightforward answer is the one which saved me.  here, I didn't even notice the -more simple- alternative 1&2 solutions given.  Too bad :(

Comment: @Balmipour Data > Pivot Table > then just copy the screenshot.

Comment: Just came back here after your comment.  I didn't guess the french for "Pivot tables", was "tableaux croisés dynamiques".  Guess I could have searched a little better that day, but at least, knowing the menu option was just in "Data" allowed me to find it.

Comment: I used solution 1 but you have to use a semicolon and not a comma between parameters.
 
=COUNTIF(A3:A8;B3)

Answer (score 31):

You can use the `query` function, so if your data were in col A where the first row was the column title...

```
=query(A2:A,"select A, count(A) where A != '' group by A order by count(A) desc label A 'City'", 0)
```

yields

```
City    count 
London  2
Paris   2
Berlin  1
Rome    1
```

Link to working Google Sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N5xw8-YP2GEPYOaRkX8iRA6DoeRXI86OkfuYxwXUCbc/edit#gid=0

Comment: This technique worked well and was easier to apply in my particular case. However, oddly the query seemed to break (i.e., it would not output anything) if there was more than one distinct numerical value in the column being counted. It worked when I converted the numerical values to their string equivalents though.

Comment: @MattV. I tried adding distinct numerical values into the column being counted and the query worked just fine.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N5xw8-YP2GEPYOaRkX8iRA6DoeRXI86OkfuYxwXUCbc/edit#gid=0&range=A1:D10

Comment: To label other columns, repeat their definition exactly. In this example: `label A 'City', count(A) 'Total'`

Answer (score 21):

`=iferror(counta(unique(A1:A100)))` counts number of unique cells from A1 to A100

Comment: can you explain the function of iferror() in this case? counta(unique(A1:A100)) gave me the result I was looking for.

Comment: OP was not asking for a count of unique values but if you do want that then you could simplify it by using =COUNTUNIQUE(A:A)

Answer (score 11):

*Not exactly what the user asked, but an easy way to just count unique values:*

Google introduced a [new function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093405?hl=en) to count unique values in just one step, and you can use this as an input for other formulas:

`=COUNTUNIQUE(A1:B10)`

Comment: This will return just 1 number. The count of the unique values. However, the OP asked how to count each unique value.

Comment: @JoshuaDance You're right, but the op's post is called "count distinct values in spreadsheet". This looks like a legit answer to this precise question to me.  Just note that it doesn't count "empty cell" as a value

Comment: If you guys are fine with, I will leave it for now. Unless too many users find this a bad answer so I will delete it. @Balmipour

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: If you came from Google, this is the correct answer

Answer (score 7):

This works if you just want the count of unique values in e.g. the following range

```
=counta(unique(B4:B21))
```

Answer (score 1):

Now with the recent release of the `LAMBDA` function this can be done even more elegantly..

```
={UNIQUE(A2:A7),MAP(UNIQUE(A2:A7),LAMBDA(city,COUNTIF(A2:A7,city)))}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Solution 1 from @JSuar...

Assume your original city data is a named range called `dataCity`.  In a new sheet, enter the following:

```
    A                 | B
  ----------------------------------------------------------
1 | =UNIQUE(dataCity) | Count
2 |                   | =DCOUNTA(dataCity,"City",{"City";$A2})
3 |                   | [copy down the formula above]
4 |                   | ...
5 |                   | ...
```

Answer (score -4):

`=UNIQUE({filter(Core!L8:L27,isblank(Core!L8:L27)=false),query(ArrayFormula(countif(Core!L8:L27,Core!L8:L27)),"select Col1 where Col1 <> 0")})`

Where `Core!L8:L27` is the list in the question.