# Count unique in group by - Google Query

Tags: google-sheets

I have this table:

```
A B
1 4
2 5
3 6
1 4
2 4
3 4
```

How could I output:

```
A count
1 1
2 2
3 2
```

i.e. count records with distinct value.

I have read that in mysql I could do:

```
select A, count(distinct B) from table group by A
```

How can I transform this to Google Spreadsheet Query language?

Comment: You can use `QUERY` in google spreadsheet, but it doesnt like count(distinct b) for some reason.

Comment: possible duplicate of [count distinct values in spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380882/count-distinct-values-in-spreadsheet)

Comment: @kenorb no it's not a duplicate, the question specifically refers to Google Query.

Answer (score 10):

`=QUERY(unique(A1:B7), "select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1")`

generally, the first part makes a "table" with only unique values and the `select` counts and groups.

Answer (score 8):

One way to do it is

1- In Column C1, enter a formula `=Unique(A1:A6)`. This will give you the unique items in Column A

[image]

2- Then in Column D1, enter `=COUNTUNIQUE(FILTER($B$1:$B$6,$A$1:$A$6=C1))` and drag it down

[image]

Comment: is possible to use that formula with AJAX? I am using this https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Comment: I'm not really an expert in this; but I've seen people applying formulas and fetching the values. Would suggest some Google Rnd

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it with a QUERY, it is possible. Indeed, the QUERY function will give you a table as a result; You have to set another QUERY to set the range of the final function.

In your case:

```
=QUERY(
UNIQUE(QUERY(A1:B7;"SELECT * WHERE A is not null ORDER BY A"));
"SELECT Col1, count(Col2) WHERE Col1 is not null GROUP BY Col1")
```

As you can see, the first QUERY set the table for the second one. This is why you have to use ColX and not A for the final QUERY.

Answer (score 0):

You just add sum function on the query.

`SUM(QUERY(A1:B7,"SELECT COUNT(B) GROUP BY B LABEL COUNT(B) ''"))`

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?