# Counting unique values in 1 column based on 5 criteria?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've been trying for hours to create such a formula. I would like for it to count all unique e-mail addresses (in column G) based on five criteria. Each criterion is stored in a separate column (columns B, C, I, R, and S). I'm working in Google Sheets. Could anyone please help to correct the below formula I have so far?

```
=ArrayFormula((SUM(IF(("Startup English"='All Session Data'!B:B)*("Yes"='All Session Data'!C:C)*("IQ"='All Session Data'!I:I)*("Female"='All Session Data'!R:R)*("Syrian"='All Session Data'!S:S), 1/COUNTIFS('All Session Data'!G:G,'All Session Data'!G:G,'All Session Data'!B:B, "Startup English",'All Session Data'!C:C, "Yes",'All Session Data'!I:I, "IQ",'All Session Data'!R:R,"Female",'All Session Data'!S:S,"Syrian"),0))))
```

I've also tried this formula and get a formula parse error:

```
=IFERROR(ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER('All Session Data'G:G,('All Session Data'!B:B="Startup English")*('All Session Data'!C:C="Yes"*('All Session Data'!I:I="IQ")*('All Session Data'!R:R="Female")*('All Session Data'!S:S="Syrian"))))),0)
```

Comment: Can you please share a spreadsheet example? This post might be helpful though which is a different approach using query language https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380882/count-distinct-values-in-spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

`=IFERROR(ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER('All Session Data'G:G,('All Session Data'!B:B="Startup English")*('All Session Data'!C:C="Yes")*('All Session Data'!I:I="IQ")*('All Session Data'!R:R="Female")*('All Session Data'!S:S="Syrian"))))),0)`

Adding `*` between your conditions means `AND` (using `+` would mean `OR`).